# How can I increase the capacity of my /home/rob/downloads folder?

Tags: directory, disk-usage

My downloader, yes it is sabnzbd, says I have too little space in my home/rob/downloads folder, no idea on how to increase a folder size though......
Please some help is much appreciated! Yes, I am a newby

Comment: You don't increase a folder's size, you increase the size of the partition where the folder resides if you have unallocated space after said partition or can shrink and move some other partition to get unallocated space from. Important: Have backups!! Someone asking a question like this *will* break something.

Comment: OK, you got it, point taken!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. buy a new disk or find an old one that is suitable
2. partition, format (mkfs) in any way you like
3. mount it e.g. at /mnt/temporary/  (mkdir first)
4. mv files from ~/downloads onto it.
5. re-mount the same partition at /home/rob/downloads
6. create a fstab entry to have it appear mounted at boot

hint:
`$ mount -t auto /dev/sdc1 /home/rob/downloads`

Google "move /home" to get direct help, it will not be exactly what to do, but it will contain a lot of very similar things.

You will be learning a good bunch of new stuff.
And finally `think!` - that is all you need.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Still got some searching to do since I have 55 Gigs left on my SSD, so no idea how this happens but should be able to sort it. Will get a new dis anyways to be sure, cheers Hannu.

Comment: An SSD is always too small, mechanical disks for mass storage! :-)